# What is the best way to use ajax loading for model with dynamic segments router v2

Tags: ember.js

I'm facing the problem with dynamic segments router v2.
here is the link for js "http://jsfiddle.net/q9zvU/5/".

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();
App.deferReadiness();

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'campaign-app'
})
App.Router.map(function(match) {
    this.route('campaigns', {path: '/:type'})
})


App.CampaignsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        alert('called model method');
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            async: false,
            data: {
                json: JSON.encode([{
                   name: 'Campaign 1',
                   type: 'scheduled'
                }, {
                   name: 'Campaign 2',
                   type: 'scheduled'
                }, {
                   name: 'Campaign 2',
                   type: 'draft'
                }])
            },
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(json) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                data = json;
            }
        })
        return data;
    },
    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render({outlet: 'campaigns'});
    }
})
App.CampaignsView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'campaigns'
    })
})
App.advanceReadiness();
```

The model method of route isn't calling with linkTo and transitionTo. (It is clearly stated in ember's doc).
But for my case, I really need to have a point to load the data from ajax request in route.

Thanks,
Linn

Answer (score 0):

Ember Documentation on the model hook:

> "A hook you can implement to convert the URL into the model for this
>   route."

So the model hook is just called on page refresh. But this confuses a lot of people :-). So, this is not the right hook in this case. I think you should use the setupController hook for this case. Try this:

```
App.CampaignsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller) {
        alert('called setupController method');
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            async: false,
            data: {
                json: JSON.encode([{
                   name: 'Campaign 1',
                   type: 'scheduled'
                }, {
                   name: 'Campaign 2',
                   type: 'scheduled'
                }, {
                   name: 'Campaign 2',
                   type: 'draft'
                }])
            },
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(json) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(json));
                data = json;
            }
        });
        controller.set("model",data);
    }
});
```

**A little extra remark:** It seems awkward that you do not wrap your objects in an Ember.Object. Normally you do not work on ordinary JS objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
My code isn't complete with missing controller. I use ArrayController in this case.

So I have another problem with transitionTo and {{linkTo}}. According to ember doc, I need to pass the real object instead of params of route. But as my requirements, I really need to do ajax query to retrieve according to types.
Seems not working with this approach.